# Why is my SwiftUI animation not working when added?

Tags: animation, swiftui, transition

There are plenty of other answers but they go into detail.  I'm trying to learn some aspects of SwiftUI and this was the basic bit of code provided here:

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/showing-and-hiding-views-with-transitions

This couldn't be any simpler and it's not working.  I would expect a red rectangle to fade in.

```
struct AnimationTestView: View {
    
    @State var isShowing = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Button("Testing") {
                withAnimation {
                    isShowing.toggle()
                }
            }
            
            if isShowing {
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.red)
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                    .transition(.opacity) // or try .asymmetric(insertion: .scale, removal: .opacity))
                
                // this doesn't work when it gets added.
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AnimationTestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AnimationTestView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me (Xcode 14.3.1). Try running with a simulator instead of in a preview.

Comment: that was it.  just didn't work in a preview.